# How much faster is Dual Channel than Intel's Flex Memory Mode?

Tags: ddr, dual-channel

How much faster is a RAM configuration of sticks `8+8+4+4` than one of `8+8+8`?  I'm interested in delay and speed in MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a [processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Supporting_processors) that supports [`Triple-Channel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Triple-channel_architecture), the second version (`8+8+8`) would be faster.

The first version (`8+8+4+4`) would only support [`Dual-Channel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture).

About the Triple-Channel memory architecture:

> The architecture can only be used when all three, or a multiple of three, memory modules are identical in capacity and speed, and are placed in three-channel slots. When two memory modules are installed, the architecture will operate in dual-channel architecture mode.

The delay and the speed of this difference are hard to tell.
I do not know of any measuring in this regard.
He who has any reliable information in this regard should stand up and tell.

Comment: What about sual-channel processors?

Comment: Your processor/mainboard combo has to support _Triple-Channel_, of course. If this combo only supports _Dual-Channel_, you are limited to this. You can check if your processor supports _Triple-Channel_ by visiting the link I provided.

Comment: I'd expect software that is "hardware agnostic" (in the relevant sense) to show any differences in speed, if there is any detectable difference - e.g. google "memtest86"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a board and chipset that only supports dual channel and NO support for triple channel .... in other words a board circuitry has to be laid out with a 3rd physical memory lane for any chipset or cpu  soldered to it that support triple channel memory configuration to be of any use, then 8+8+4+4 would be faster.

**On a system that only supports dual channel**

8+8+4+4 if configured in the proper DIMMs could be run in dual channel mode.

Depending on if they were configured 8+8+4+4 or 8+4+8+4, one of these configuration would produce FLEX or Hybrid mode resulting in 16GB in dual mode and 8GB running in single mode. This depends on your board Dimm slot configuration.

8+8+8 on a dual channel board can only produce a FLEX/Hybrid setup that is 16GB in dual mode and 8gb in single mode.